# printf and unsafe formatting strings

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, user-input

The application in question allows users to define their own messages (mainly for customization and/or localization purposes) in plain-text configuration file, which are passed to printf-style functions at runtime. If the user-defined formatting string is faulty, a whole lot of bad things can happen.

What is the best way to sanitize such user-inputted formatting strings? Or should I drop this approach entirely and use another method to let users safely customize the messages?

Solution must be somehow portable (Windows, Linux, BSD, x86, x86-64).

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO30-C.+Exclude+user+input+from+format+strings - don't do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your own formatting language, which your code translates into a valid format string, thereby restricting what trouble the user can get into (for example, not allowing % at all, and defining your own symbol/marker to use to indicate a % should appear in the output).

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Let the user's mess-ups (intentional or not) mess up *only* themselves, i.e. don't let the users' personal configurations interfere with each other
2. Don't let users customize the results.  Or if you do, make the customization so limited that there is nothing they can do that is harmful.
   For example, I've frequently done things where users are allowed to provide their own input to things like `printf()`, but the filters only allowed for things with a certain (very limited) character set.  E.g., I'll use a regexp of something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$` and don't let anything else in.

Any time you offer customization, you open the door to problems.  Walk carefully in these grounds.